# Swift - Timer.publish(:) misfires

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui, combine, runloop

I have a timer scheduled as following:

```
private var timerCancellable: Cancellable?

timerCancellable = Timer
        .publish(every: 1.0, on: .current, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .scan(-1) { counter, _ in counter + 1 }
        .sink { counter in
            print("\(counter)")
            
        }
```

This works fine (print out 0 1 2 3 ...) when I test it on any normal view controller. But in a specific view controller which I a live camera feed with Metal shaders (and several different DispatchQueue instances), it gives this output:

0
0
1
2
3
...

0 is repeated twice. I tried .main for RunLoop but the result is the same. Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this would be debuggable without a [mre].

Comment: I would guess it's initiated twice. However, if you are trying to calculate elapsed time like that this is extremely imprecise.

Comment: It's initiated only once @Sulthan

Comment: Why are you trying to do with the timer?  As @Sulthan says, counters and `Timer` are not a good way of tracking elapsed or remaining time. They suffer from inaccuracy and jitter. You should use a faster timer (for smoothness) and a `Date` from which you can track elapsed or remaining time

Comment: Forget about why I want this timer, it's not the question.